# Java - search for substring in array

Tags: java, arrays, search, substring

I am trying to find a subString inside a string, in an arraylist, but I can't get it working.
It has to loop through the arraylist until it finds the sub string, and then stop.

Here is what I have so far

```
    private static void teamSearch(String teamName) {

    String subString = teamName;
    String string = "";
    boolean contains = false;

    while (contains = false){
    for (int i = 0; i < clubList.size(); i++){
        string = clubList.get(i).aliases;
        contains = string.contains(subString);
    }
    System.out.println(contains);
    }
}
```

Any help in getting this working would be much appreciated :)
Thank you!

Comment: Don't use while, break the for loop when `constains` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner for loop keeps on rolling - even if it finds the the alias with the substring.

You need to terminate the loop when it finds a match. This is a naive, yet correct implementation

```
private static void teamSearch(String teamName) {

    String subString = teamName;
    String string = "";
    boolean contains = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < clubList.size(); i++){
        string = clubList.get(i).aliases;
        if (string.contains(subString){ 
          contains = true;
          break;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(contains);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
while (contains == false)
```

instead

```
while (contains = false)
```

`=` is an assign operator and `==` is comparision operator. you are assigning false to contains in while loop. You have to compare the values

Answer (score 1):

Avoid while loop. Use break statement. If not careful, while loops can cause infinite loops.

```
private static void teamSearch(String teamName) {
    String subString = teamName;
    String string = "";
    boolean contains = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < clubList.size(); i++){
        string = clubList.get(i).aliases;
        if (string.contains(subString)) {
           contains = true; 
           break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(contains);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition is wrong change it to `while ( contains == false )`

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign a value there.you need to check  the value equal or not

```
while (contains == false) //checking equality


while (contains = false) //assigning
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
while (!contains) {...}
```

But it might be easier to simply drop the `while` loop and `break` the `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < clubList.size(); i++){
    string = clubList.get(i).aliases;
    contains = string.contains(subString);
    if (contains) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be useful

```
boolean flag = false;

    String subString = "nice";


    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(2);


    arrayList.add("good morning");


    arrayList.add("that is nice");


    for (String element : arrayList) {


        if (element.contains(subString))


            flag = true;


        else


            flag = false;


    }
```